# Django templates: Calling super in case of multi-level extends

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my current template structure:

```
example_template_1.html
example_template_2.html extends example_template_1.html
example_template_3.html extends example_template_2.html
```

How would I get content of a specific block from `example_template_1.html` in `example_template_3.html`? Basically, I need something that does `{{ block.super.super }}` in `example_template_3.html` to override the contents of a specific block in `example_template_1.html`.

Is that possible?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible as of [django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template).  I'd recommend refactoring your templates.

Comment: I would restructure the templates so that each block is it's own template, render these as needed in python code to html strings, mark those as safe and embed them into the big template, where they are combined accordingly.